# split CLOB field into table like structure

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have field in a Oracle database of type CLOB. I would like to split this field in several columns and rows. Here's an example of the content:

```
4:true5:false24:<p>option sample 1.</p>4:true22:<p>option sample 2.</p>5:false23:<p>option sample 3.</p>5:false22:<p>option sample 4.</p>5:false
```

The result should look like this:

```
ID LEVEL ANSWER_OPTION VALUE
1   3   option sample 3 false
1   4   option sample 4 false
2   3   option sample 3 false
4   3   option sample 3 true
3   2   option sample 2 false
1   2   option sample 2 true
2   1   option sample 1 true
2   4   option sample 4 false
4   1   option sample 1 false
2   2   option sample 2 false
4   2   option sample 2 false
1   1   option sample 1 false
3   4   option sample 4 false
4   4   option sample 4 false
3   3   option sample 3 false
3   1   option sample 1 true
```

We have made the following statement which created the result above.

```
with guest_string as 

(    select qsn.id                                id 

     ,      dbms_lob.substr( qsn.guest, 2000, 1 ) answer_options

     from   mneme_question qsn

     where qsn.id < 10 

)

select distinct id
,      level
,      substr(regexp_substr( answer_options'<p>[^<]+', 1, level, 'i'), 4) ANSWER_OPTION
,      substr(regexp_substr( answer_options, '(true|false)', regexp_instr( answer_options, '</p>', 1,  1), level, 'i'), 1) VALUE
from   guest_string
connect by regexp_substr( answer_options, '<p>[^<]+', 1, level, 'i') is not null
```

The problem with this code is it takes way to long to split all records we have. We had to cut it off at 10 rows (5 row take 0.25 sec, 10 takes 16 seconds, 15 rows takes about over 2,5 minutes). We currently have 30000 rows and they will grow. At the moment we cannot change the software to change the datamodel, so we will have to do this ad hoc.

Our current approach is to create a procedure that will be called for each record, but it would be better to have a faster parsing. Does anybody have a suggestion how to create a script that can do this in a reasonable time. We can do this at night time, but preferably it shouldn't take longer than 2 minutes.

BTW in the future we could build some sort of mechanism to determine which records have already been parsed, but that also requires some form of detecting already parsed fields that have changed in the mean time. We don't have time to do that yet, so for now we need crude parsing as fast as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different approach.

The code may not be as nice as it can, and you will probably have to fix some small things...
I checked it on 11g (couldn't find 10g) and used your input as the values in my clob column.
For 10 rows (all with the same input as you gave as example),
**original query:** 9.8 sec
**new query:** 0.08 sec

I used a pipelined function, here is the code:

```
create or replace type t_parse is object(idd number, levell number, answer_option varchar2(128), valuee varchar2(4000));
/
create or replace type tab_parse is table of t_parse;
/
create or replace function split_answers return tab_parse
  pipelined is
  cursor c is
    select * from mneme_question;

  str_t   clob;
  phraseP varchar2(128);
  phraseV varchar2(8);
  i1s     number;
  i1e     number;
  i2s     number;
  levell  number;

begin
  for r in c loop
    str_t  := r.guest;
    levell := 1;
    while str_t is not null loop
      i1s := dbms_lob.instr(str_t, '<p>', 1, 1) + 3;
      if i1s = 3 then
        str_t := '';
      else

        i1e     := dbms_lob.instr(str_t, '</p>', 1, 1);
        phraseP := dbms_lob.substr(str_t, i1e - i1s, i1s);
        str_t   := dbms_lob.substr(str_t, offset => i1e + 4);

        i2s := dbms_lob.instr(str_t, 'true', 1, 1) ;
        if i2s = 0 then

          i2s := dbms_lob.instr(str_t, 'false', 1, 1) ;
          if i2s = 0 then
            str_t := '';
          else
            phraseV := dbms_lob.substr(str_t, 5, i2s);
            pipe row(t_parse(r.id, levell, phraseP, phraseV));
            levell := levell + 1;
          end if;
        else
          phraseV := dbms_lob.substr(str_t, 4, i2s);

          pipe row(t_parse(r.id, levell, phraseP, phraseV));
          levell := levell + 1;
        end if;
      end if;
    end loop;

  end loop;
  return;
end split_answers;
/
```

new query should be like:

```
select * from table(split_answers);
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an alternative solution. We are making progress with the patttern of calling a procedure. We will try your solution as well. We have also come up with an improved version of the code.

Comment: This is the improved version: `with rn as (select rownum rn from dual connect by rownum < 10)
select
substr(regexp_substr(qsn.guest, '<p>[^<]+', 1, rn, 'i'), 4) ANSWER_OPTION,
substr(regexp_substr(qsn.guest, '(true|false)', regexp_instr(qsn.guest, '</p>', 1,  1), rn, 'i'), 1) VALUE
from mneme_question qsn
cross join rn
where substr(regexp_substr(qsn.guest, '<p>[^<]+', 1, rn, 'i'), 4) is not null`
It still needs testing, but it was faster than the original

Comment: ok @BetaUser, these are my results: for a table with a clob column and 20 records all with the same value (the one from your post) I got: original qry: **342.219** ; your new qry: **0.375** ; my qry: **0.11** , but there is a strange thing- the original and my queries returned 80 records but your new one returned 380

Comment: Ok, many thanks for your help. Performance has gone way up. I think we'll manage from here. I'll mark your post as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is some function whis returning pipelined table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_clob(p_clob      IN CLOB DEFAULT NULL,
                                      p_varchar   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                      p_separator IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN varchar_set
  PIPELINED IS
  l_clob CLOB;
BEGIN
  l_clob := nvl(p_clob,
                to_clob(p_varchar));

  FOR rec IN (

                WITH vals AS
                 (SELECT CAST(TRIM(regexp_substr(l_clob,
                                                 '[^'||p_separator||']+',
                                                 1,
                                                 levels.column_value)) AS
                              VARCHAR2(320)) AS val
                    FROM TABLE(CAST(MULTISET
                                    (SELECT LEVEL
                                       FROM dual
                                     CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                                                length(regexp_replace(l_clob,
                                                                      '[^'||p_separator||']+')) + 1) AS
                                    sys.odcinumberlist)) levels)
                SELECT val FROM vals)
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW(rec.val);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
```

U can use it like this:

-with table with clob

```
  SELECT t2.column_value FROM my_table t, TABLE(split_clob(p_clob => t.clob_column,p_separator => ',')) t2
```

-or with varchar too

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(split_clob(p_varchar => '1,2,3,4,5,6, 7, 8, 9', p_separator => ','))
```